# using angular/Http headers are not getting passed with the request

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, I am trying to invoke a REST service to get a list of Organizations that will be used to fill a dropdown on the signup page. My login page is working fine, i get a token back and store it in localStorage. Based on the console.log() statements, during signup flow this token is getting retrieved as well, but it is just not getting passed in the header with the request. Here is the headers list from chrome dev tools.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmQZS.png)

Here is my http.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor (public http: Http) {}

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    console.log('HttpService createAuthorizationHeader called');
    let tok = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token;
    console.log(tok);
    //headers.append('X-Authorization', 'Bearer  ' + tok);
    headers.set('X-Authorization', 'Bearer  ' + tok);
  }

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    console.log('HttpService get called- ' + url);
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
   /* let tok = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token;
    console.log(tok);
    //headers.append('X-Authorization', 'Bearer  ' + tok);
    headers.set('X-Authorization', 'Bearer  ' + tok);*/

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log(headers.toJSON());
    return this.http.get(url, options).map(res => res.json());
  }

  post(url, data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
      this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post(url, data, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
}
```

This is how I am calling it

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {HttpService} from './http.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Organization} from '../../model';

@Injectable()
export class OrganizationService implements OnInit {
  orgs: Organization[];
  constructor(private http: HttpService) { this.http = http}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit OrganizationService called.');
  }
  getOrganizations(): any {
    console.log('getOrganizations OrganizationService called.');
    // get the token here from localstorage and add to header.
     return  this.http.get('http://localhost:9966/api/getOrganizations')
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log( result );
    });
     /* .map((res) => {
      console.log('got http response');
      console.log(res.json());
      return res.json();
    } );*/

      //return this.orgs;
  }
}
```

Problem is that 'X-Authorization' header value is not passed with the request. That is why the server is sending back 401 status. I tried using RequestOptions also, still same issue. Appreciate any help in this

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the answer to fit your structure.

**HttpService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  createAuthorizationHeader(): Headers {
    let tok = 'My token';
    return new Headers({ 'X-Authorization': `Bearer ${tok}` })
  }

  get(url): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader() }).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**OrganizationService**:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

@Injectable()
export class OrganizationService {

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  getOrganisations(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.get('/api/organizations');
  }
}
```

**SignupComponent**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrganizationService } from '../organization.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private orgranizationService: OrganizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orgranizationService.getOrganisations().subscribe(resp =>
      console.log(resp));
  }
}
```

Request:
[image]

Comment: @LL, seems like any headers I add are going under "Access-Control-Request-Headers". See the dev tools output.                          
"OPTIONS /api/getOrganizations HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9966
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/signup
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"

Answer (score 0):

Your are using RequestOptions, but the get-method requires RequestOptionsArgs. Just change your code to this:

```
get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

    let options = { headers: headers }; // HERE
    return this.http.get(url, options)
       .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Markus and LLL for your help. I think I figured out what was going on. ts the CORS in action. 
I was using Chrome for testing, and Chrome being more secure, send a pre-flight OPTIONS request, which does not contain the headers I was adding. I had to handle the OPTIONS request on the server side by not responding with 401. now Chrome is sending the second request (after the OPTIONS is successful), with proper header.

Tests from IE worked fine with my original server side code. :)